# Is many-to-many association still apply here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-framework, database-design, many-to-many

When an entity isn't associated with **many** other entity **at the same time**, should I still use many-to-many association?

For example, I understand that Author-Book relationship is a many to many, An author can write many books, a book can be written by many authors. This holds for all time.

Consider this situation. A Batch has many students at one particular time. If a student fails, he should move to the next junior batch. In other word, **A student cannot belong to more than one batch at the same time**. In this case, is this a many to many association?

**Alternative Solution I thought:**
I was thinking about putting two columns in students table. `initial_batch` and `current_batch`. I can get the student's Batch history, by checking the gaps between current and initial batch, because of the rule **A student must drop to the next immediate batch**. Also, `batch.students` exists with a `has_many` association in rails. So, I think that would not be a big deal.

---

By Batch, I mean batch of students get admitted in the same year.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd still want to use an association table (many-to-many association) because you might want to keep a history of which classes the student has taken.

If you want it to be a many-to-one and have a student belong to one class at a time, you'd have to add a `class_id` field to your student table. This allows you to call `student.class` to find their current class, but you wouldn't be able to do `class.students` because that relation doesn't exist. For this reason, I think it should be a many-to-many.

Comment: That is a good point, which i also was thinking. I was considering `initial_class` and `current_class` column in student, and I can get the student's class history, by checking the gaps between current and initial class, because, A student must drop to the next immediate class. Also, `class.students` exists with a `has_many` association. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> is this a many to many association

Yep.

An ActiveRecord association is simply a way for you to create two connected objects ([ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#active-record-as-an-orm-framework) is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) -- *Object Relationship Mapper*).

*Remember*, as Ruby is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), each "Model" (class) is counted as an object, invoked every time you want to populate it with data. Each ActiveRecord association for each object is accessed through a *method* in the object...

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subjects #-> AR appends the "subjects" method to your Student object
end
```

Simply, this means that even if you have the functionality for a number of different objects, you don't need to have the method populated with data.

---

If you have the following...

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end

#app/models/subject.rb # "class" is a reserved word
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

This simply provides the functionality / capacity for `@students.subjects` etc.

What's contained *inside* this method is up to you to determine:

```
<% if @students.subjects.any? %>
  <% @students.subjects.each do |subject| %>
     ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I actually have many to many model, not just a join table. the model has another integer attribute which stores the fail count

Comment: Cool! Yep, same logic still applies

Comment: That brings another question, how do I get the students of the most current batch. However, that might be asked in another question

Comment: To give a specific answer, I'd need to know how you're separating the batches

Comment: first_column is a `batch_id` and second one is `student_id`, third one is `drop_count`. unique index on [`batch_id`, `drop_count`]

Comment: Can you post your model setup too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92627/discussion-between-anwar-and-rich-peck).